# How do I compute this Jacobian?

Tags: calculus

Calculate the Jacobian of
$\Phi$$(r,\theta)$= $(5r\cos\theta, 4r\sin\theta)$

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do you have a definition of "Jacobian" to work with?

Comment: I'm given this formula but I'm not so sure how I should apply it to this problem: $\frac{\partial(x,y)}{\partial(u,v)}$=$\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial v}$ - $\frac{\partial x}{\partial v}$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$

Comment: @nkbminh: that is the formula for the determinant of the $2\times 2$ matrix that represents the derivative of your function.

Comment: How do I perform the partial derivative in my given problem? Can you please give me some more help?

Comment: I've posted an answer. do you know what a gradient is?

Comment: A gradient and a gradient vector are the same thing right? If that's the case then I think I know what it is.

Comment: yes, that's right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jacobian is just the gradients of the two components of $\Phi$, stacked into a matrix. (The gradient of the first component, $\Phi_1=5r\cos\theta$, goes in the first row, and the gradient of the second component, $\Phi_2=4r\sin\theta$, goes in the second row.) In general, the Jacobian of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ will be an $m\times n$ matrix, where the gradient of the first component goes in the first row, the gradient of the second component goes in the second row, and so on, until you put the gradient of the $m$-th component in the $m$-th row.

In your problem, the gradient of $\Phi_1=5r\cos\theta$ is $$\langle\frac{\partial \Phi_1}{\partial r},\frac{\partial \Phi_1}{\partial \theta}\rangle=\langle 5\cos\theta, -5r\sin\theta\rangle$$ and the gradient of $\Phi_2=4r\sin\theta$ is $$\langle\frac{\partial \Phi_2}{\partial r},\frac{\partial\Phi_2}{\partial \theta}\rangle=\langle 4\sin\theta, 4r\cos\theta\rangle$$ so your Jacobian matrix is $$\begin{pmatrix} 5\cos\theta & -5r\sin\theta\\4\sin\theta & 4r\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}$$

Or, if "Jacobian" for you means the *determinant* of that matrix, you'll get $$20r\cos^2\theta+20r\sin^2\theta=20r(\cos^2\theta+\sin^2\theta)=20r$$

Comment: This is so much easier to understand than what my professor teaches in class. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome! You can also "upvote" answers you find helpful by pressing the up arrow.

Comment: It says I need at least 15 reputation to "vote up" an answer. I'm sorry...